# How to check if HTML style attribute exists with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I'm trying to find out if a specific element has an inline style attribute or not:
I'm sure there's an easy method to check this, but I can't seem to find it.
I tried multiple things already including this:

```
var contentWrapper = document.getElementById("contentWrapper");
if(contentWrapper.style.display.toString=="")
alert("Empty");
else
alert("Not Empty");
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if attribute exists or not in Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579452/how-can-i-check-if-attribute-exists-or-not-in-jquery)

Comment: `getAttribute('style')`

Comment: Also, be careful when calling functions to make sure you add parenthesis. `display.toString == ""` is comparing the **function** , when you want to compare the **return value** of the function.  It should be `display.toString() == ""`.  (Not that you need `.toString()` here anyway, as `display` is already a string, but it's another reason why your code might fail)

Comment: The two duplicates linked provide solutions in jQuery which is not explictly asked for by the user; therefore, this is not a duplicate of either of those questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if(!contentWrapper.getAttribute("style"))
```

OR

```
if(contentWrapper.getAttribute("style")==null || 
   contentWrapper.getAttribute("style")=="")
```

the above lines will work for you (anyone can be chosen).

In second solution:

first check watches if `style attribute` is present in the element, 2nd check ensures that `style attribute` is not present as an `empty string` e.g. `<div id="contentWrapper" style="">`

Complete code is given below:

```
var contentWrapper = document.getElementById("contentWrapper");
if(contentWrapper.getAttribute("style")==null || contentWrapper.getAttribute("style")=="")
alert("Empty");
else
alert("Not Empty");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/fjuZW/ (1st Solution)

http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/fjuZW/1/ (2nd Solution)

Comment: The double check is unecessary, since both, `null` and `''` are falsey. Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.hasAttribute would be better.

Comment: 2nd check is to make sure that style attribute is not present as an empty string e.g. <div id="contentWrapper" style="">

Comment: I know, but what I mean is that `Boolean('')` is `false`. So `if (!contentWrapper.getAttribute('style')) { //empty }` works for `null` or `''`.

Answer (score 19):

```
if(contentWrapper.getAttribute("style")){
    if(contentWrapper.getAttribute("style").indexOf("display:") != -1){
        alert("Not Empty");
    } else {
        alert("Empty");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not so perfect for commentarized strings like this "/* font-size: 24px; */". In this case it works as if font-size exists.

Answer (score 1):

I missed @plalx's comment the first time I scanned this page.

```
if (element.hasAttribute("style"))
{
    var styleText = element.getAttribute("style")
}
```

---

On a related note, regarding styles...

```
//to get info about the end results of CSS
var computedStyle = element.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(element, null);
```

and

```
//to iterate over css styles from style tags or linked CSS
for i ...
    document.styleSheets[i].rules ...

//great for searching with
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(rules[i].selectorText);
```

Answer (score 1):

The style object has a `length` property which tells you if the element has any inline styles or not. This also avoids the problem of having the attribute `style` being present but empty.

```js
// Would be 0 if no styles are applied and > 0 if there are inline styles applied
contentWrapper.style.length
// So you can check for it like this
contentWrapper.style.length === 0
```

Answer (score 1):

**To check style attribute exist or not for given Id**

```
if(document.getElementById("idname").hasAttribute("style")){
  alert("Style attribute found");
}else{
  alert("Style attribute not found");
}
```